# Is it possible hide Facebook Connect app showed at Facebook search? Or use same app id for Facebook connect and  an another apps

Tags: facebook

We need both a Facebook Connect (requires  a facebook app) and a normal Facebook app for the same company. Normal app is outsourced and its URL different than company (they have different developer account). We made the facebook connect app. But when a user search company's name it show two apps ( facebook connect and normal app) and it seems confusing for users. Users most probably want to search normal app. It is possible hide Facebook connect app showing user search or unify these two apps? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to hide an app once it is in search, but it is now necessary to submit your apps to search: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/523/

It may be helpful to know that you can use a single AppID for Connect, Canvas, Page Tabs and Mobile. You can put the user into the relevant context based on how they interact with shared content.

This is the recommended approach as when the user goes through the permissions dialog and authorises your app, they will then be logged in wherever you use that AppID. You wouldn't need them to authorise your Canvas and Connect apps separately, for example.

Comment: Different URLs for what?
The answer depends on how your application is designed. Some people implement a HTTP Referer check to decide whether to redirect traffic to Canvas or Connect apps, for example.